# NGINX SSL Config (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

Tags: nginx

Could someone please look at this configuration file and tell me what I am doing wrong?

Using the curl command: curl -4 https://example.com
I get the following error:
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number

When trying to access from Firefox I get: Error code: SSL_ERROR_RX_RECORD_TOO_LONG

The site is accessible via standard http://

```
server {
      listen 80;

      server_name example.com www.example.com;
    
      root /var/www/example.com/html;
      index index.html;

      location / {
             try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
      }
}

server {
      listen  443 ssl;
      server_name example.com www.example.com;
      ssl_certificate    /etc/ssl/nginx-ssl/bundle.crt;
      ssl_certificate_key    /etc/ssl/nginx-ssl/certificate.key;


      access_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.access.log;
      error_log /var/log/nginx/nginx.vhost.error.log;
      location / {
      root   /var/www/example.com/html;
      index  index.html;
      }
}
```

```
VHOST ACCESS LOG
173.255.234.116 - - [23/Jun/2021:17:38:17 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x00\xEE\x01\x00\x00\xEA\x03\x03>\x88\xABg\xFC\xC1A\xFC7\x01\x9B\x07C76\xFE\xF3\x14\x0BQ\xAAYV]\x8F\xB8\xF1/\xF0\x0C\xA7G \xCC\x19\xFEi\xDE\x87\xF4\xF0\xF5\x1D\xD1x\xA3C\xFB\x97)\xF0\xD9\xAD6\x99\xA3UP\x81\x8A\xC2\xA0\x09yv\x00&\xC0/\xC00\xC0+\xC0,\xCC\xA8\xCC\xA9\xC0\x13\xC0\x09\xC0\x14\xC0" 400 166 "-" "-"
65.154.226.109 - - [23/Jun/2021:17:40:17 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03\xAA\x9F#\x06\xEFqr\xAC\x8B\x8F\xDA \x1A\xBB\xA9Ez4\x09\xE6\x9A\xB3k\xF8PC\xA7)%\x00\xFB\x94 \xA7\xCC\x00=f\x9F\xCD\x8E^\xFAbn\xCB\xC5Z\x07#\xF5:\x8Au^\xCB\xF1\xEC-\xDF%\xD3?\xE8t\x00\x22\x1A\x1A\x13\x01\x13\x02\x13\x03\xC0+\xC0/\xC0,\xC00\xCC\xA9\xCC\xA8\xC0\x13\xC0\x14\x00\x9C\x00\x9D\x00/\x005\x00" 400 166 "-" "-"
77.68.112.214 - - [23/Jun/2021:17:41:19 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03d\x1D_\x97\x9Az\x18\xEDl4\x1D\xA8#\xB3\xFF" 400 166 "-" "-"
77.68.112.214 - - [23/Jun/2021:17:43:48 +0000] "\x16\x03\x01\x02\x00\x01\x00\x01\xFC\x03\x03$E" 400 166 "-" "-"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It definitively something with your certificate.

I've tried your configuration with self signed certificate in docker:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UlqHG.png
[image: your config running in docker]

I hope it's readable.

Try with self signed certificate.

The command I use to generate self signed certificate:

```
openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:4096 -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365 -nodes
```

Leo,

Comment: Many thanks Leo I’ll try that in the morning. Do you have a link to some instructions on preparing and installing .crt’s for Nginx? Thanks again.

Comment: Thank you Leo, you were right, it was the certificate in the end.

Comment: Happy to help solving your problem

Comment: Well - this response it almost useful... @Radial - please, saying "it was the certificate in the end" is a terrible way to conclude this.  Please explain what you did to fix the issue otherwise this entire thread is just noise.

Comment: Hi Destek, maybe you should contact Leo, who's instructions I followed and as a result accepted his answer.

Comment: Hello, the problem was inside the certificate or the key. Probably a missing character or a badly generated certificate. I can't provide more information about this problem because I haven't seen the contents of the certificate.

Answer (score 0):

**1st option:**
It's probably because your double space between listen and 443.

```
listen 443 ssl;
```

**2nd option:**
Check your certificate and your key with:

```
openssl x509 -in certificate.crt -text -noout
```

```
openssl rsa -in privateKey.key -check
```

Sincerly,

Comment: Thanks Leo, thank you for your suggestions. I've corrected the double space, but I still have the same error. Also, both of the keys seem to check out.